# CSS to center text - Canvas Wootheme

Tags: css, wordpress, canvas

I'm using Wordpress theme Canvas by Woothemes.  I'm trying to center the site description text underneath the logo.  Here is the site:  http://barkhascustomsourcing.com

Here is the current CSS I am using.  It's not responsive, I know, but I need to re-write so it is.

```
#logo .site-description {
    display: inline-block !important;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin-left: -330px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To make this properly responsive you will have to do a lot more than only adjust this class. Heres how you can implement it for your header section:

```
#logo { width: 100%; }
#logo > a {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 350px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: block;
}
#logo > span.site-description {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: block !important;
}
```

By making the outer and inner box following the full width but constraining them with `max-width` will make them responsive.

Now, this is only a small part of your site. I'm not doing the entire thing for you here, but you get the general gist. It also requires you to look at almost any elements, as resizing will require you to make elements that take up a natural; height and expand as their width decreases. So actually, you *cannot* use any pixel based `widths` or `heights` anywhere, only `max-widths` and `max-heights`.

PS: Next time you ask a question, please include what you have tried yourself. Show us that you are not outsourcing your work to us :)

Answer (score 0):

Following things you need to update.

```css
#logo {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
#logo .site-description {
  line-height: 25px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: block !important;
}
```